# How to create 2 different curves with a continuous holding loop

Tags: modeling, mesh, edges, topology

I have read that it is a best practice to try to keep continuous lines in a mesh, and doing so is leading me into some strange situations that seem incorrect.

In the example here, I have a holding loop that is being used to set 2 different edges. It remains continuous but now the overall mesh has a weird flow to what should be a straight/flat grill section.

[image]

Here is the result I need.

[image]

The reason this topology feels off to me is that the curve in the mesh facing the camera is on a flat surface that will be squared out into a vehicle grill. The grill itself should have squared up topology and this curve going through it seems like it will directly conflict.

The result I have achieved in the second image is correct, but I'm hoping to create the same curves with better topology.

Comment: Could you please expand a bit and tells us why it why it has a "weird flow"? It is also not very clear what end result you want to achieve or how it is different from what you have now. Please edit your question and provide more details.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos, I have updated by questions. Hopefully that helps clarify. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: You can, and probably should keep said grill as a separate object from the main body, or even in the same object, but as a separate chunk of mesh, disconnect from the rest, unless you specifically need a continuous surface

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. So you would suggest modeling the nose of the vehicle as I have and then adding the grill separately as to avoid conflicting with the mesh?

Comment: Yes, I don't know what the final purpose of the model will be, so I can't really give an informed advice. Unless this is for a game engine or anywhere where polycount is an issue, or this will be used for 3D printing or any purposed where a continuous mesh us required then I guess you could model it separately.